# Possible to left align button text but right align background or button image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Hi I have a `UIButton` created in Storyboard where I would like to left align the title but right align the image.  So far, I've been unable to find a way to do it.  I know it is possible to add a separate UIImage but for purposes of simplifying autolayout I was hoping to do it all with one button.

Is such a thing possible either in storyboard or with code?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overwrite this in subclass:

```
- (CGRect)titleRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect;
- (CGRect)imageRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect;
```

then use this subclass in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

My `UIButton` extension methods, in Swift. Sorry about it's not `obj-c`. My projects are almost written by `Swift` now.

```
extension UIButton {
    // ## Usage
    // let btn: UIButton = //... UIButton
    //
    // ... configure `image` and `text` before calling following method. 
    // btn.myImageRightAligned()
    // Let image of `UIButton` aligned right. 

    public func myImageRightAligned(_ spacing: CGFloat = 2.0) {
        let button = self
        guard (button.imageView != nil && button.imageView?.image != nil) else {
            return
        }
        guard (button.titleLabel != nil && button.titleLabel?.text != nil) else {
            return
        }
        let imageSize = button.imageView!.image!.size
        let title = button.titleLabel!.text! as NSString
        let titleSize = title.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: button.titleLabel!.font])

        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: -(imageSize.width + spacing), bottom: 0.0, right: imageSize.width)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left:  titleSize.width, bottom: 0.0, right: -(titleSize.width + spacing))

        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change button image offset (changing position) from element inspector in storyboard, i don't get the meaning of aligning the background as it covers the whole button there is no left and right in this